# Как построить таблицу

Tags: sql

Как построить таблицу и зависимость связей попутчиков. 
Есть маршруты дороги которые имеют свои характеристики,и они складываются с участков дорого например маршрут номер 1 на такой то машине.... ну кучу там инфы и этот маршрут  складывается с точек Москва Киев Варшава Париж.
Я сделал так таблица way которая имеет свой id и кучу других пунктов и таблица subway которая имеет id way_id.... ну связи тут понятны. Все бы ни чего если бы не поиск
ввожу я например "от Киева" и запись номер один должна выпасть так как я могу поехать попутчиком по данному маршруту, когда я ввожу "от Киева" "до Варшавы" тоже должна выпасть данная запись и если я введу "до Парижа" или "до Варшавы" или "до Киева" тоже запись должна выпасть...но если я введу "от Парижа" или "до Москвы" запись не должна выпасть...

Знаю что вопрос очень длинный и не простой но помогите.

Comment: кто поможет?

Comment: задача так и не решилась

Answer (score 3):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

1. Таблица маршрутов. Что-нибудь вроде справочника Id-Name
2. Таблица городов. Та же самая структура
3. Маршрут делится на сегменты. Если у нас есть маршрут A-B-C, то он, как видим, состоит из двух сегментов - A-B и B-C. Поэтому следующей таблицей будет таблица сегментов. Примерно следующей структуры: Id, RouteId, StartPoint, EndPoint, SegmentNumber, где RouteId - идентификатор маршрута, StartPoint и EndPoint - начальная и конечная точки сегмента, ссылающиеся на значения из таблицы городов, SegmentNumber - порядковый номер сегмента в маршруте, нужен для определения очередности прохождения внутри маршрута.

Допустим, вам нужен маршрут, где конечным участком является Воронеж-Тула-Москва. Сделать это можно так:

```
SELECT r.RouteName
FROM Routes r
JOIN Segments s ON s.RouteId = r.Id
WHERE 
        (s.SegmentNum = 5 AND s.EndPoint = 'Воронеж') -- разумеется, идентификаторы
    AND (s.SegmentNum = 6 AND s.EndPoint = 'Тула')    -- должны быть int'ами 
    AND (s.SegmentNum = 7 AND s.EndPoint = 'Москва')  -- названия лишь для наглядности
```

Если вам не известны заранее позиции городов в маршруте (скажем, просто нужны те маршруты, где есть участок Воронеж-Тула-Москва вне зависимости от того, находится ли этот участок в начале, в середине или в конце маршрута) то можете просто отобрать все маршруты, включающие в себя Воронеж, Тулу и Москву, а уже на сервере приложения отфильтровать те, что не подходят по очередности городов в маршруте или каким-то другим признакам.

Еще я бы вам очень рекомендовал почитать про теорию графов - она занимается в том числе и задачами, связанными с поиском маршрутов. Думаю, ознакомившись с ней, вы сможете более грамотно подойти к вопросу.

Comment: идея классная но зачем хранить,участки да и где вы учли последовательность

Comment: теорию графов смотрел

Comment: >теорию графов смотрел

смотрели или знаете? 

>зачем хранить,участки

Для того, чтобы сохранялась ссылочная целостность базы. Можете в одной строке хранить только конечную точку сегмента и его номер. Разницы в принципе не будет

>где вы учли последовательность

Про последовательность писал же - для этого существует поле SegmentNum. Оно определяет последовательность сегментов в маршруте.

Comment: и зачем хранить отрезки а не каждую точку

Comment: >и зачем хранить отрезки а не каждую точку

вы очень невнимательно читаете. я уже писал, что вы можете в одной строке хранить только конечную точку сегмента и его номер (ну и еще id маршрута)

Comment: Я так и делаю,но не получается отфильтровать данные, DreamChild  можно Вашу почту?

Answer (score 1):

Два поля у каждого города: откуда сюда можно приехать, и куда отсюда можно уехать. Дальше-просто перебор.

вот есть у нас такая таблица:http://jsfiddle.net/PLUua/
таким образом мы сможем попасть из Парижа в Киев, так как в полях откуда и куда записанны эти города

Comment: извините вы не правильно поняли вопрос,маршруты создаються и через один и тот же город может быть н маршрутов

Comment: Не вижу в чем проблема :(

Comment: Пояснил, должно быть все понятно

Comment: Да вы сами задачу не поняли, на не нужно знать от куда и куда мы можем добраться(это не задачка по теории грфов) нам нужно найти маршрут который удолитворяет требованием, и в маршруте точек может быть не две от куда куда а 10

Comment: >Да вы сами задачу не поняли

боюсь, не он один, поскольку объясняете вы очень плохо - запутанно и косноязычно

Comment: извините что так объяснил.Сейчас попробую подробнее.

Comment: 1)я создаю маршрут(он имеет в себе информаци о себе ) и точки через которые он проходит которым я хочу Москва Воронеж Киев Прага Берлин Париж. 
2)Маршрутов может быть много через одну точку а точек в маршруте  может быть не больше  десяти и они идут только в том направлении в котором они созданы

Comment: 3)Допустим маршрут F-C-A-D и есть два поля поиска от куда и куда(они могут заполнены оба или по одному) если я ввожу в поле "от куда" F,C,A то выпадет данный маршрут но если я введу D то не выпадет ибо данная точка в нем последняя, если я Введу в поле "куда" C,A,D тоже выпадит этот маршрут но если F он не выпадет так как F начальная точка так же я могу этот маршрут если запоню от куда F,C,A и куда C,A,D одновременно

Хотелось бы увидеть идею как создать бд и запросы по поиску.

Answer (score 1):

Такая идея, если я правильно понял задачу. Таблица points для ключевых точек (населенных и иных пунктов). В ней 2 поля: id записи и point - название ключевого пункта. Таблица маршрутов routes. В ней 2 поля: id записи и route - маршрут из id-номеров ключевых пунктов, через которые лежит маршрут, сохраненный в виде строки, в которой пункты разделены символом точки (это для разбиения строки на массив ключевыех пунктов). Например, в points : 1 - Киев, 2 - Чернигов, 3 - Конотоп, 4 - Сумы. Маршрут из Киева в Сумы: "1.2.3.4". Потом нужно выбрать стартовый и финишный пункты из значений таблицы points - $start, $finish. Делается выборка из routes и дальше перебираются все значения. Значение поля route разбивается на массив функцией explode

> $points = explode(".",$row['route']);

затем условие if(in_array($start,$points) && in_array($finish,$points)) { оба пункта есть в массиве, данный маршрут подходит. Можно вывести таблицей или как будет угодно; }

P.S. Правда по этому условию подойдёт и маршрут в обратную сторону. Поэтому надо проверять, чтобы индекс значения в первой проверке in_array был меньше второго.

Comment: задачу вы поняли правельно, но я думаю нужно сделать запросом одним. так как вы поймите это же будет в филтре и выводиться будут 20-30 маршрутов(это уже с учетом пагинации)

Comment: Тут по-любому нужен запрос к таблице пунктов, чтобы задать начало и конец маршрута. А потом запрос для маршрутов. Так что 2 минимум.
Что значит в филтре?

Comment: @Zepp вы слышали о ссылочной целостности баз данных? Ваше решение  с маршрутом в виде строки, содержащей идентификаторы, как раз нарушает ссылочную целостность

Comment: Не слышал. Спасибо, надо будет погуглить.

Comment: не один метод пока не работает. Вернее я еще до этого создал бд... но запрос сделать не как.

Comment: вот ссылка на дамп таблиц http://us.ua/1261161